# How to multiply a vector and a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a 20 by 1 vector Amp, and a 3D matrix M 100 by 20 by 100.
I want to multiply each element of Amp to its corresponding slice in M.
I already achieved this by a for loop as follows:

```
Result = zeros(100,20,100);
for i=1:20
   Result(:,i,:) = Amp(i)*M(:,i,:);
end
```

But I wonder if there is anyway to make this faster. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
Result = bsxfun(@times,Amp.',M);
```

Comment: I think you need `Amp.'` instead of `Amp`

Comment: I tried this and it makes it faster, anyway to make it even faster?

Comment: @Alithewise No.

Comment: @Alithewise How much time does this actually take with the matrix size you specified? Around a millisecond? How much faster do you want it?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Correct. Transposing is required.

Comment: @beaker I want to run this program in another for loop and I want to make it real time, so I want to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: @Alithewise Profile first, **then** optimize.